# Can't load material properties from Naviswork/Revit file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-navisworks

On a recent project I have loaded a building into Forge. (nwd file, originally from Revit).

The properties (including dimensions like volume) transfer completely for concrete. However, masonry walls show no properties in Forge.

Any idea how to get all of the properties moved over to Forge (specifically dimensions) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I checked one of my Revit model, it looks the masonry wall has the properties dimensions... http://autode.sk/2xaUJ0Z , but maybe I misunderstood something. If my test model is not the same scenario like yours, could you provide  a small sample file to share? if so, please send to forge.help[at]autodesk.com (please do not send confidential information)

Comment: We can view the property dimensions in Revit, but they disappear when the project is opened in Forge.

Comment: Hi, could you send us a reproducible sample file? We will diagnose what it happened with the file when translating.. thank you.